# Why 960 grid doesn't divide into "fours"?

Tags: css

I've just wanted to start my adventure with a CSS framework, but I have a problem, which I'm not able to overcome. I've added 960.css and my own stylesheet.css but it persistently won't divide the content into "fours".

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Grid test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/960.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" /> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container_12 clearfix">
    <div id="header" class="grid_12">
    <h1>Logo</h1> 
    <div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Products</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">About</a></li> 
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul> 
    </div>

    </div>
    <div id="feature" class="grid_12">
        <p>Feature</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="article grid_4"> 
        <p>Column One</p>
    </div>

    <div class="article grid_4">
        <p>Column Two</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="article grid_4"> 
        <p>Column Three</p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" class="grid_12">
<p>© Copyright 2011</p> </div>
  </div><!-- .container_12 -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif; color: #665544;
text-align: center;}
#nav, #feature, .article, #footer {
  background-color: #efefef;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;}
#feature, .article {
  height: 100px;}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;}
```

Comment: All you have there is the HTML. Please post the CSS.

Comment: You should put your code in the question.